# What is a deterministic random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X$ be a (real-valued) random variable on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ with
\begin{equation}
    \text{Var}X = 0.
\end{equation}
Is it correct to call X deterministic?

I understand that if $\text{Var}X = 0$ then there exists a constant $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $X = c \; \text{a.s.}$. So I guess my question is do I require
\begin{equation}
    X(\omega) = c, \hspace{6mm} \forall\omega \in \Omega
\end{equation}
for $X$ to be deterministic or is being equal almost surely sufficient?

Comment: Almost surely is sufficient.

Comment: It depends on definition. If we identify functions up to sets of measure $0$, then I think we could call $X$ deterministic.

Comment: @Jakobian thanks, thought as much. I wasn't sure it there was a standard definition

Comment: I am not sure there is a "standard" definition of a deterministic random variable. However, in the context of random variables, I think the name is clear enough by itself to be used safely. Any realisation of $X$ will produce the same value.